# May I have remote git repository on my hosting?

Tags: git, repository, hosting

I had been using free github account as a remote repository. Now I am wondering if I can create a github repository on my hosting. There is a `git` command present on it, but is it enough? I am not permitted to install anything on my hosting. How to check if I can place github repository there.

If it was the posibility to have github a repository there, how to create it? What internet address would it have?

Comment: This question doesn't have anything to do with code

Comment: So what? Questions like this are worse?

Comment: you can read about git init --bare

Comment: @Ebrahim Poursadeqi it did not help.

Comment: @trzczy yes, questions like this are not good. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hosting and see for yourself. The list is very extensive, and over 50% are of poor quality and should be removed

Comment: I am not going to create any fake code just to get to know what is required to place a git repository on typical hosting.

Comment: No, GitHub is not available for self-hosting, but there are plenty of other options for self-hosted git servers, GitLab is quite popular for example.

Comment: Pro Git book has a chapter dedicated to the subject: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols

Answer (score 0):

you can try [Bitbucket host on your server](https://bitbucket.org/product/pricing?tab=host-on-your-server) its free for a team less than 5 members but more than it, won't, and also you can have it on your host.

Comment: I am not going to have anything to do with github. I am going to have a git repository on my hosting. When I say hosting I mean a service that i have bought from a company that give people a storage on their server, a webserver and database etc. I am going to write some code on my several local computers and push and pull data with the repository. May I use my hosting for it? How to create the repository on it and how to retrieve a git repository address for it?

Comment: Perheaps my English is too bad. You do not understand me. I give up. I want to have git repository on my hosting. No github, no bitbucked. Only typical hosting that has apache, mysql and where git command is present. Thank you anyway. I go to 'server fault' community and ask.

Comment: My Friend I know.what you want,and the first I provide its exactly foe the same reason,it be be on cloud and server, you must choose server and download it foe.your server

Comment: @trzczy I updated link path to where exactly you need to download it and up and run your host

Answer (score 0):

[Gitlab community](https://about.gitlab.com/products/) could be the solution too.
If you have more than 5 users.